# Terraform fails using an Azure service principal for authentication

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

## Problem

Terraform gives the following error when trying to use `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` after create a service principal in Azure:

> provider.azurerm: No valid (unexpired) Azure CLI Auth Tokens found. Please run `az login`.

## Steps to Reproduce

Create a service principal in Azure via `az ad sp create-for-rbac`.

Add the service principal configuration as a provider block to your `.tf` file:

```js
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "tf_bootstrap"
  client_id = "55708466-3686-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_secret = "88352837-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  tenant_id = "129a861e-a703-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  subscription_id = "c2e9d518-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dev" {
  name     = "dev-rg"
  location = "East US"
}
```

Attempt to run `terraform plan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the `alias` key in a [provider block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html), as shown in the question, a `provider` key must be specified in **each** data or resource blocks.

For example:

```js
// When a provider alias has been defined.
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dev" {
  provider = "azurerm.tf_bootstrap"
  name     = "dev-rg"
  location = "East US"
}
```

If you miss a `provider` for one of your resources or data blocks, authentication fails on that block.

---

Note however that is also valid to *not* specify an `alias` key in the original provider block. In that case, it is no longer necessary to specify a `provider` key in every resource and data block; the `provider` key can be omitted.

```js
// When a provider alias has not been defined.
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dev" {
  name     = "dev-rg"
  location = "East US"
}
```